# Where does ABAQUS calculate velocity?

Tags: nodes, element, abaqus

I am a relatively new ABAQUS user and I am trying to figure out whether ABAQUS calculates velocity at the nodes or at the integration points of an element. I think it calculates stresses/strains at the integration points and displacements at the nodes but I could be mistaken. If this is correct, then my guess would be that the displacements are differentiated to obtain the velocities but I don't know. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Abaqus you can find this out by just looking at the categories of output variables - stresses and strains are integration point variables while displacements and their derivatives (velocities, accelerations) are nodal variables.